How to measure energy consumption of python code running on CPU?
I want to measure the energy consumption of a python code which is running on a traditional cpu.
For example, the code is
a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
b = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

# this is the code I want to measure:
c = a @ b

I wonder if there is a method that can tell me the duration and energy consumption of c = a @ b, such as duration = 2ms and energy consumption = 1.38mJ.
I have tried a tool called pyJoules as below, it says it can measure the energy footprint of python code:
from pyJoules.energy_meter import measure_energy
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)

@measure_energy
def foo():
    # Instructions to be evaluated.
    z = x @ y

foo()

and I get the output as below, only duration, no energy consumption:
begin timestamp : 1713528811.3988383; tag : foo; duration : 0.02333545684814453; nvidia_gpu_0 : 0

So please help me get the energy consumption, it's really important for me!!! Thank you all!

according to the documentation your gpu's energy consumtion (in uJ) is listed... device_name: power consumption of the device device_name in uJ and it looks like it's basically nonexistent, have you tried size 10000?

you are measuring GPU and code is using CPU, take a look once again at pyJoules documentation and add some arguments to the decorator

I strongly advise you to check the results of software methods using a physical measures. I personally used physical measure and found out that all software tool tested was providing clearly biased results so they are not reliable. This is dependent of the target machine and target code. Some software methods make assumptions that are totally wrong in practice (like the energy consumption grow linearly with the number of core, or that the RAM accesses have no impact on the energy consumption, etc.).

A simple naive physical test is just to run that on a PC and check the energy meter of your house/apartment. It is not very accurate compared to specialized physical tools or integrated probes (since the consumption is global), but often significantly better than software methods I tested so far.

@dankal444
Thank you for point out my problem. I had modified the code and measure the energy consumption of gpu: x = torch.randn(1000, 1000).to(device) y = torch.randn(1000, 1000).to(device), and I get the result: begin timestamp : 1713615753.7997453; tag : foo; duration : 1.6112899780273438; nvidia_gpu_0 : 32893. It means when I calculate z = x @ y on my own RTX 2060 gpu, the energy consumption is 32893uJ, right?

@sadpencil according to authors of this package, yes :) I never used or even installed pyJoules, so cannot help much more
